# SPA site served via react-router does not load unless you've visited the homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

If you navigate to my React site's homepage it loads fine, however if you first open `/some-link` then you'll hit my CDN's `page not found` error. So long as you open the homepage first, you can navigate to any other links. If the site has been loaded before, you can open `/some-link` just fine by typing in the URL.

My router looks like the following:

```
                <Router>
                    <Wrapper>
                        <Header />
                        <Body>
                            <Switch>
                                        <Route
                                            path="/some-link"
                                            component={SomeComponent}
                                        />
                            </Switch>
                        </Body>
                        <Footer />
                    </Wrapper>
                </Router>
```

Comment: What's the web server? You have to configure some type of URL rewriting on the server.

Comment: Web server is netlify's static CDN

Comment: This will get you going in the right direction: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, assuming your home page is index.html, you should just need an _redirects file with this in it:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

All of the details are available here:

Comment: Beautiful thanks! More info for netlify here - https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Comment: Also important to note: if you're using react or something like that to build your app, `_redirects` needs to be in the root of the build output (not the root of your project directory). That silly mistake took me awhile. Also, you can use the full netlify configuration file, `netlify.toml`, for redirects instead if you like https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/